# Meteor CollectionFS: How to prevent duplicate files?

Tags: meteor

I can't seem to find a 'checksum' property on a CollectionFS object. I'd like to have it to prevent duplicate files from being uploaded.

Is there any best-practice approach to prevent duplicates?

Should I do it myself client side and append to the CollectionFS object?  I didn't want to create another mongo collection to track the files.

Comment: yes, I think you'll have to compute and add a checksum yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is normally to hash the file *contents* (excluding the metadata) with for example, md5, and then store the hash key with the collectionFS object itself (Once you have a document _id you can update that document with a new key). Index on the hash for quick comparison against prior documents.